# I want to add editing functions using Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuex

## What I want to come true

I am creating TodoLists.
I tried to implement the following editing features, but it didn't work and I'm having trouble.

1. Click the edit button to display the edit text in the input field
2. If you click the save button after entering the changes in the input field, the changes will be reflected in the first position.

## Code

```
      <v-row v-for="(todo,index) in todos" :key="index">
        <v-text-field
          filled
          readonly
          :value="todo.text"
          class="ma-3"
          auto-grow
        />
        <v-menu
          top
          rounded
        >
          <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
              v-bind="attrs"
              icon
              class="mt-6"
              v-on="on"
            >
              <v-icon>
                mdi-dots-vertical
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item
              link
            >
              <v-list-item-title @click="toEdit(todos)">
                <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                Edit
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item
              link
            >
              <v-list-item-title @click="removeTodo(todo)">
                <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
                Delete
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
        </v-menu>
      </v-row>

      <v-text-field
        v-model="itemText"
        filled
        color="pink lighten-3"
        auto-grow
        @keyup.enter="addTodo"
      />
      <v-btn
        :disabled="disabled"
        @click="addTodo"
      >
        Save
      </v-btn>
```

```
  data () {
    return {
      editIndex: false,
      hidden: false,
      itemText: '',
      items: [
        { title: 'Edit', icon: 'mdi-pencil' },
        { title: 'Delete', icon: 'mdi-delete' }
      ]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    todos () {
      return this.$store.state.todos.list
    },
    disabled () {
      return this.itemText.length === 0
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addTodo (todo) {
      if (this.editIndex === false) {
        this.$store.commit('todos/add', this.itemText)
        this.itemText = ''
      } else {
        this.$store.commit('todos/edit', this.itemText, todo)
        this.itemText = ''
      }
    },
    toEdit (todo) {
      this.editIndex = true
      this.itemText = this.todos
    },
    removeTodo (todo) {
      this.$store.commit('todos/remove', todo)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
export const state = () => ({
  list: []
})

export const mutations = {
  add (state, text) {
    state.list.push({
      text
    })
  },
  remove (state, todo) {
    state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1)
  },
  edit (state, text, todo) {
    state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1, text)
  }
}
```

## Error

Click the edit button and it will look like this
[image]

## What I tried myself

```
//methods
 toEdit (todo) {
      this.editIndex = true
      this.itemText = this.todos.text //add
    },
// Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

For some reason I get an error that I couldn't see before

Comment: 2 things: you should not commit mutations but use `dispatch` and call actions. Your mutations are taking 3 params but this is not the way how it works. Check this link: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#Vuex-store-instance-methods and this one too: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#mutations Also, give a read to the guide, it may help you understand Vuex better.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Made the parameter an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties/data types in your code are a bit mixed up.

Here you're accessing `state.todos.list`...

```
todos () {
    return this.$store.state.todos.list
},
```

...but in your store the const `state` doesn't include `todos`:

```
export const state = () => ({
  list: []
})
```

Furthermore, you're writing to `itemText` the content of `todos`, which should be a string but actually is an object - which leads to the output of `[object Object]`.

```
toEdit (todo) {
    this.editIndex = true
    this.itemText = this.todos
},
```

Also, please check out kissu's comment about the mutations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.sorry. I forgot to write the important thing.todos exists as a file in the store.